# Is there any way I can write "unified" Node.js and browser JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I'm writing an Electron app and I'll be using both Node.js and browser style JavaScript.

Node.js modules have to be written like this:

```
module.exports = class {
    ...
}
```

Whereas browser JavaScript modules are written like this:

```
export default class {
    ...
}
```

But lets say I want to write module exports that work in both mediums for the same project without code duplication. Is there a way?

Assuming there are no Node.js specific features, even dependencies from many browser-friendly node.js modules should be able to double as browser style code and the other way around. Something like web-pack?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.matteoagosti.com/blog/2013/02/24/writing-javascript-modules-for-both-browser-and-node/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js modules ***do not*** need to be written that way. Only modules that still use the legacy commonjs format do.

If you're writing new code, do yourself a favour and add `type: "module"` to your `package.json` file, and then just write normal modern JS with `import` and `export`. This has been supported in Node since v12 with a runtime flag, and out-of-the-box since v14 (which is the current LTS version).

See https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html for all the details you want to know.

Comment: did not know about that runtime flag

Answer (score 1):

I want to add some extra information, I hope it also could help you.
When you use `type: modules` in node.js, there are some differences.
Like, you could not use `__dirname` in node.js with `type: modules`.
Instead, you need to use `import.meta.url` as replacement.
You could take a look [esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_differences_between_es_modules_and_commonjs) for more details.